# Microsoft Access 2016 cannot create ACCDE on Windows Powershell using SysCmd 603

Tags: powershell, microsoft-access

I would like to have some help from you.

I'm using Office 2016 Professional, so Access 2016. On Windows Powershell, I'm trying to create "nice.accde" database from "nice.accdb". My code is (in test.ps1):

```
$objApp = New-Object -com "Access.Application.16"
$i = $objApp.SysCmd(603, "nice.accdb", "nice.accde")
$objApp.Quit
```

I got this error, sorry my Windows is in French, so is message:

> Impossible de convertir l'argument «Action» (valeur «603») de «SysCmd» en type «Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction»: «Impossible de convertir la valeur «603» en type «
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction» en raison de valeurs d’énumération non valides. Spécifiez l’une des valeurs d’énumération suivantes et réessayez. Les valeurs d’énumération possibles
>   sont «acSysCmdInitMeter;acSysCmdUpdateMeter;acSysCmdRemoveMeter;acSysCmdSetStatus;acSysCmdClearStatus;acSysCmdRuntime;acSysCmdAccessVer;acSysCmdIniFile;acSysCmdAccessDir;acSysCmdGetObjectState;acSysCm
>   dClearHelpTopic;acSysCmdProfile;acSysCmdGetWorkgroupFile».»
>   Au caractère test.ps1
>   +       $i = $objApp.SysCmd(603, "nice.accdb", "nice.accde")
>   +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

What's the error ?

SysCmd 603 worked with Access 2007, but not on Access 2016 ?

Comment: Sure enough, 603 is not in the list of valid values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/acsyscmdaction-enumeration-access

Comment: So accde creation using automation is definitively out of date ?

Comment: Oh, I don't know if it is or not. What did you think the 603 value was for? Where did you come up with that command?

Comment: I used this value to create automatically accde file without using Access 2007 user interface... then using Windows Powershell to copy to everywhere in our Ethernet Network (LAN). This value is very known and old, you could just do a google search with syscmd 603.

Comment: Aaah...it is an undocumented value. It seems to work and not work at various times and for various reasons. There are long protracted discussions over different methods where it has or has not worked. I doubt that you are going to get a single silver bullet solution.